# CUDA. Почему при вычислениях на GPU скорость операций с float и double примерно одинакова?

Tags: производительность, float, double, cuda, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Я проводил исследование эффективности использования GPU и CPU, float и double для решения больших и сверхбольших разреженных СЛАУ и столкнулся с расхождением ожидаемых и полученных результатов.

Предполагалось, что GPU должно проводить вычисления с float значительно быстрее чем с double, но на практике разница в скорости незаметна. Реализация программы производилась с использованием CUDA.

Я написал простенький тест, но и он показывал одинаковое время вычислений.

```
#include "iostream"
extern "C++" {
   #include <cublas_v2.h>
};
//****COMMENT FOR USE DOUBLE****
#define USE_FLOAT

#ifdef USE_FLOAT
typedef float value_type;
#define CUDA_DOT cublasSdot_v2
#else
typedef double value_type;
#define CUDA_DOT cublasDdot_v2
#endif

void test(){
    cublasHandle_t cublasHandle = nullptr;
    checkStatus(cublasCreate(&cublasHandle));
    cublasSetPointerMode(cublasHandle, CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE);
    value_type *tmp;
    cudaMalloc(&tmp, sizeof(value_type));
    time_point start;
    time_point stop;
    for (__int64 i = 2; i < INT64_MAX; i = i * 2) {
        unsigned long long dur = 0;
        value_type *ttt = new value_type[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            ttt[j] = 0.0001;
        }
        value_type *a;
        value_type *b;
        checkStatus(cudaMalloc(&a, i*sizeof(value_type)));
        checkStatus(cudaMalloc(&b, i*sizeof(value_type)));
        checkStatus(cudaMemcpy(a, ttt, i*sizeof(value_type), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        checkStatus(cudaMemcpy(b, ttt, i*sizeof(value_type), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

        delete[] ttt;

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
            start = clock_type::now();
            CUDA_DOT(cublasHandle, i, a, 1, b,1, tmp);
            stop = clock_type::now();
            dur += getDuration(start, stop);
        }
        checkStatus(cudaFree(a));
        checkStatus(cudaFree(b));
        dur /= 1000;

        std::cout << dur << std::endl;
    }
    cudaFree(tmp);
    cublasDestroy(cublasHandle);
}

int main() {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Видеокарта на которой происходят вычисления:
[image: характеристики GPU]

Может кто-нибудь объяснить в чем дело, и почему float не работает быстрее double?
Был бы очень благодарен =)

---

Результаты полученные мной с помощью этого теста. Время указано в наносекундах
[image: результаты теста]

Comment: а где Ваши результаты тестов? Но что то мне подсказывает, что Вы тестируете скорость цикла for, а не скорость cuda.

Comment: ¿Вы утверждаете, что успешно выделяете на своей машине с 16 Гб памяти массив из `INT64_MAX / 2` (4 611 686 018 427 387 903) double и обрабатываете его на видеокарте с 2 Гб памяти? Сильное заявление...

Comment: меня это тоже озадачило, но я решил, что я просто с утра неправильно понял код.

Comment: @KoVadim, в цикле я провожу замер времени вычисления скалярного произведения векторов, различных размеров. Т.е. я провожу 1000 вычислений скалярного произведения, и вычисляю среднее время вычислений для текущего размера векторов и вывожу его в консоль.

Comment: представьте, что время вычисления в теле цикла меньше, чем накладные расходы на сам цикл (или соизмеримы с ним). В этом случае Вы не увидите сильной разницы. Во вторых - Вы тестируете не разницу в double/float, Вы тестируете как библиотека это реализовала. А там вполне может быть приведение к одному типу или совершенно разные алгоритмы.

Comment: @user7860670, нет, не утверждаю. Этот тест был написан на скорую руку, но то, что программа выдает исключение о недостатке памяти на k итерации не мешает получить значение замеров для предыдущих итераций.

Comment: вынесите clock_type::now(); за пределы цикла. Эта функция не такая и дешевая, как Вам может показаться и она может вносить много-много искажений. Плюс ко всему, у нее есть своя точность. И если Ваши вычисления граничат с этой точностью - у Вас проблема.

Comment: ¿И какие значения замеров получаются?

Comment: Эти значения стоило бы добавить в вопрос

Comment: ага, и добавить обязательно нужно картинкой. Ну что бы можно было прочитать:)

Comment: @KoVadim и user7860670, спасибо, что уделили внимание моему вопросу, все оказалось довольно просто =)

Перед подведением итогов скорости, потоку выполняемому на хосте следовало дождаться окончания вычислений на видеокарте, я добавил после цикла for(int j...) вызов метода cudaDeviceSynchronize();

В итоге я получил более ожидаемые результаты время выполнения вычислений на double растет быстрее чем на float.

Вероятнее всего в основной работе, сказался тот факт, что разреженные матрицы с которыми я работаю содержат относительно небольшое кол-во элементов

Comment: как всегда - измеряли попугаев в вакууме:)